# How can I create a whole new console window for a new cmd.exe process?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd, console-application

I'm in the process of creating a game engine inside a Windows 10 console. The goal now is to simulate frames. All is good with one exception - I need a way to display logs outside of the program before I get more into frame machine implementation. So I want to have a new process of a console in a new window just to do some logging in my debug compilations.

I've found the [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) function, however its documentation seems rather incomplete.

I filled the call as follows:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof si);
si.cb = sizeof si;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof pi);

LPCWSTR appName { L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe" };
//LPCWSTR appName { L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe" };

CreateProcess (
    appName,        
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    FALSE,          
    0,              
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    &si,            
    &pi         
)
```

I observed that the `appName` variable that points to Notepad creates a new window as expected, however when pointed to `cmd` it creates a process in the same console window.

How can I create a console process in a new window, from a console program?

I'm also open for other logger implementation ideas.

Comment: Solved! thank you! That was quick! Also a GUI app thats a good idea i will think about it. Post it as an answear and i give this question solved mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag in the `dwCreationFlags` parameter of `CreateProcess()`. See [Process Creation Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags):

| Constant/value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE 0x00000010 | The new process has a new console, instead of inheriting its parent's console (the default). For more information, see [Creation of a Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console). This flag cannot be used with `DETACHED_PROCESS`. |
| DETACHED_PROCESS 0x00000008 | For console processes, the new process does not inherit its parent's console (the default). The new process can call the [`AllocConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) function at a later time to create a console. For more information, see [Creation of a Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console). This value cannot be used with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. |

But, why use a separate process for logging? Just have your main console process create a separate GUI window using [`CreateWindow/Ex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa), and then it can display your log messages as needed, such as with a multi-line [`EDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls) control, or a [`LISTVIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-control-reference) control in report mode, etc.  Then there will be no need to deal with [inter-process communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications), marshaling your log data across process boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (since you asked `just to do some logging`), just write to a log file and use a `tail`-like utility to display it in real time.

Another alternative: use [`OutputDebugString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) and the [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) tool.

Comment: Also note that when a debugger is attached to the process calling `OutputDebugStringW()` you don't need any other tool to get to see the output. Visual Studio, for example, will display the text in the debugger's output pane. Alternatively, you can [log info with tracepoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-tracepoints), with the added bonus that you do not need to touch the source code to enable logging. And you get string interpolation for free, so you don't have to write any formatting code.